# Stata - Marginal effects

Tags: margins, stata

is there anybody who could briefly go through the program mymargin and check for any inconsistencies and possible extensions/improvements, ... The program should estimate the marginal effect of any variable in the sample selected by if and in should build on the saved results from a previous logit regression.

```
capture program drop mymargin

program mymargin, rclass
version 10.1
syntax varlist(max=1 numeric) [if] [in] [, atmean]
marksample touse
quietly count if `touse' == 1
if `r(N)' == 0 {
error 301
}   

local res me mme
tempname `res'
quietly summarize `varlist' if `touse'==1, detail

scalar `me' = // TBU
display as txt "Marginal effect of" `var' ": " `me'

if "`atmean'" == "atmean" {
matrix r = r(stats)
scalar `me' = normalden(_b[sex]*r[2,1]+_b[ageinyears]*r[3,1] +_b[meduc]*r[4,1] +_b[hhinc]*r[5,1] +_b[area]*r[6,1] + _b[_cons])
}
display as txt "Mean marginal effect of" `var' ": " `me'    

foreach r of local res {
return scalar `r' = ``r''
}

return scalar N = r(N)      // return the number of observations
return local var `varlist'  // return the name of the variable
return  // TBU, return the (mean) marginal effect

end

mymargin hhinc
return list
display me
display mme
```

Answer (score 1):

This would get a failing grade from me, if only because of the wired-in assumptions that you have five specified predictors in a specified order:

```
scalar `me' = normalden(_b[sex]*r[2,1]+_b[ageinyears]*r[3,1] +_b[meduc]*r[4,1] +_b[hhinc]*r[5,1] +_b[area]*r[6,1] + _b[_cons])
```

Also, the `summarize` command will zap any `r(stats)` left behind by any previous command.

Regardless of Stack Overflow's general policy, that's as far as I will go personally in helping with what appears to be an assignment for a course. See your previous post about a week ago.